# Question involving an invertible complex matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, similar-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix with complex entries and call $A = R + iJ$, where $R$ is the real part of $A$ and $J$ is the imaginary part of $A$. Show that there exist a $\lambda_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $R+ \lambda_0J$ is invertible. Futhermore, conclude that if $A$ and $B$ are matrices with real entries and they are similar in $\mathbb{C}$ then they are in $\mathbb{R}$.

I've tried to prove the first statement by contradiction, but what kind of things I can do if $\det(R+xJ)= 0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$??

Also, I cannot see the conection with the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are similar in $\mathbb{C}$, then they are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the complex polynomial $\lambda \mapsto \det(R + \lambda J)$. Note that it is non-zero when $\lambda = i$, so it is not the zero polynomial. Thus it has finitely many $0$s in the complex plane, which means we cannot have $\det(R + \lambda J) = 0$ for all $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$.

Now, suppose that $A$ and $B$ are real matrices, and $P = R + iJ$ is a complex invertible matrix such that
$$B = P^{-1}AP \iff PB = AP \iff RB + iJB = AR + iAJ.$$
Equating real and imaginary parts,
\begin{align*}
RB &= AR \\
JB &= AJ.
\end{align*}
By the previous exercise, we can find some $\lambda_0 \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $Q = R + \lambda_0 J$ is invertible. We therefore have,
$$QB = RB + \lambda_0 JB = AR + \lambda_0 AJ = AQ \implies B = Q^{-1} AQ,$$
proving real-similarity.

Comment: Nice, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first part: as you did, consider $f(x)=\det(R+xJ)$ as a polynomial function (with real coefficients) of some degree $n$ in $x$. You know that $f(i)\ne 0$. So not all coefficients are $0$. But by contradiction, without loss of generality $f(1),f(2),... f(n+1)$ are equal to $0$. There are no non-zero polynomials of degree $n$ with that property, a contradiction. So indeed for some integer $k$ between $1$ and $n+1$, $f(k)\ne 0$ and the matrix $R+kJ$ is invertible.

The second part is not true for every pair or complex $A,B$. You probably missed some conditions.

Comment: Can you give me a counter example?

Comment: **Counterexample:** Take a real matrix $A=((2,1),(1,1))$ and complex matrix $C=((0,i),(i,0))$. Then $A$ and $B=CAC^{-1}$ are conjugate but not by a real matrix because $A$ has real entries but $B$ has some non-real values.

Comment: Any other questions?

Comment: No, thanks you. I've forgotten to say that $A$ and $B$ has real entries, so your counter-example works without this statemant.